# How to migrate string data type to hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.3

I am upgrading my rails 3 application to rails 4. And according to the guide I removed this line from my model

```
serialize :my_serialized_column, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore.new({})
```

but now I am getting the error while looping over `:my_serialized_column` which was previously hash

> undefined method `each' for "":String

Now my question is how do I change the data_type of my column without losing the data I already have

Comment: You had hstore in rails 3? Rails 4 still has hstore. Why migrate to a different column type?

Comment: In rails 3 column data type is `string`  we are serializing the column

Answer (score 2):

So you can just change the data type of the column from `string` to `hstore`.

One thing to keep in mind is you need to cast the data to hstore or you will get the following error

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "my_serialized_column" cannot be cast automatically to type hstore
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING my_serialized_column::hstore".
```

To avoid the error you can specify the casting

```
class ChangeMySerializedColumnTypeToHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_null :my_table, :my_serialized_column, ''
    change_column :my_table, :my_serialized_column, "hstore USING my_serialized_column::hstore"
  end

  def down
    change_column :my_table, :my_serialized_column, :string, default: ''
  end

end
```